# How to make super-user permissions last longer than using sudo?

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo, password

Is there a way through which I can make the `sudo` command give me permissions for a longer period than its default time?

It can be a pain having to keep entering the `sudo` password, when requiring the installation of many packages, so it would be nice if there exists a command or configuration that can be done to affect it usage period.

Comment: So, nobody uses `su` any more? Ever?

Comment: @MrLister `sudo -i` and you have a root shell, ready for anyone to help shoothing themselves in the feet during as much time one like...

Comment: @DevRobot, do you have a source for that? I find it kind of hard to believe that Canonical would remove such an important command, and I can't find anything about it on google.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem All of the Ubuntu installs I've ever used, at least by default, had disabled the ability to use su to get a root shell. I think you can enable (or install?) it manually, though. You can also just use `sudo -i` or `sudo bash` or similar.

Comment: @DevRobot `su` needs root to have a password. By default, Ubuntu's root user doesn't have a password. Therefore, you can't `su` to root. `su` is working as intended here. Try with any user who has a password.

Comment: @muru `sudo su` works just fine, though a bit repetitive.

Comment: @coteyr `sudo su` works because `su` is executed as root, and the default Ubuntu configuration allows root to `su` without passwords.

Comment: kinda what I meant. It's not that su is disabled, just that you have to execute it as root, instead of typing your root password (which by default doesn't exist)

Comment: @MrLister Ubuntu (and possibly Debian) and it's derivatives usually don't have a root-password set (or rather it's set to something random and/or the root-account is blocked), so you can't use `su` to become root.  It's a security measure to prevent the root-user from logging-in directly.  Using `sudo` (and `su`) from a normal user-account, logs information about who became root.

Comment: I had to install Debian 8 a few weeks ago and it does have an active root user. The installation asks for both the root password and the main user password. And after a fresh install, the user isn't even in sudoers.

Comment: @MrLister not only is the user not in sudoers, but sudo isn't even installed! You have to `su; apt-get install sudo`

Comment: @BaardKopperud It's just Ubuntu (and derivatives,) as far as I know. Normal Debian does have a normally-configured root user.

Comment: related: [Making a window for a bash script password through Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25876153/4279).  See [my comments there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25876153/making-a-window-for-a-bash-script-password-through-python#comment40545355_25876153)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Behavior of `sudo` is configured in `/etc/sudoers` file. There is `timestamp_timeout` option responsible for reprompting the user for password after specific amount of time.

From [man sudoers](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/sudoers.5.html#contenttoc4)

```
timestamp_timeout
                       Number of minutes that can elapse before sudo will ask
                       for a passwd again.  The timeout may include a frac‐
                       tional component if minute granularity is insufficient,
                       for example 2.5.  The default is 15.  Set this to 0 to
                       always prompt for a password.  If set to a value less
                       than 0 the user's time stamp will never expire.
```

To alter that setting do the following:

1. In terminal run `sudo visudo`. `visudo` is used specifically to edit `/etc/sudoers` file and by default uses `nano` text editor.
2. Find the lines starting with `Defaults`. Add the following line

   ```
   Defaults        timestamp_timeout=x
   ```

   where x is the amount of minutes you want between reprompts
3. Save the file with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

Answer (score 13):

From `man sudoers`:

```
timestamp_timeout
                       Number of minutes that can elapse before sudo will ask
                       for a passwd again.  The timeout may include a frac‐
                       tional component if minute granularity is insufficient,
                       for example 2.5.  The default is 15.  Set this to 0 to
                       always prompt for a password.  If set to a value less
                       than 0 the user's time stamp will never expire.  This
                       can be used to allow users to create or delete their
                       own time stamps via “sudo -v” and “sudo -k” respec‐
                       tively.
```

As you can see, the default timeout of `sudo` is 15 minutes. You can change this value in `/etc/sudoers`.

You don't directly edit `/etc/sudoers`, instead use `visudo` to do it.

From `man visudo`:

```
     visudo edits the sudoers file in a safe fashion, analogous to vipw(8).
     visudo locks the sudoers file against multiple simultaneous edits, pro‐
     vides basic sanity checks, and checks for parse errors.  If the sudoers
     file is currently being edited you will receive a message to try again
     later.
```

So, type `sudo visudo` in a terminal, which will open the `/etc/sudoers` file in `nano` text-editor.

Look for this line:

```
Defaults    env_reset
```

And add `timestamp_timeout=X`  where **X** is the time you want to set in minutes.

So as an example:

```
Defaults    env_reset,timestamp_timeout=5
```

If you specify 0, you will always be asked the password. If you specify a negative value, the timeout will never expire.

Once done, save and exit.

**See [RootSudoTimeout](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudoTimeout)**

Comment: Beat me by 29 seconds =)

Comment: You're good -_-b  I'm on a laptop . . . maybe i need more coffee

Comment: You can also set for example -1 to timeout -  if you never want a password prompt to trigger.

Answer (score 8):

Try this .

1. Run the following command in a Terminal:

   ```
   sudo visudo
   ```
2. Scroll down to the line that looks like this:

   ```
   Defaults        env_reset
   ```
3. Change it to for example:

   ```
   Defaults        env_reset,timestamp_timeout=30
   ```

Change 30 to the time, in minutes, that you want it to wait before it times out. You can also change it to 0 if you want a password prompt every time you run sudo, or -1 if you never want a password prompt 
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to finish editing, Y to save changes, and Enter to exit.

Here is source: http://lifehacker.com/make-sudo-sessions-last-longer-in-linux-1221545774

Answer (score 5):

You can edit the `/etc/sudoers` file (with `sudo visudo`: be careful) and add a line like

```
Defaults:myname timestamp_timeout=15
```

where `myname` is your user id. The timeout value is in minutes. You can use a value
of -1 to never expire, and then type `sudo -k` to kill the authentication, so you need
a password again.

Or you can add an entry to say a specific command does not need a password at all.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `sudo -k` to manually invalidate the cached authentication.

Answer (score 5):

I can't believe that the simplest command:

```
sudo -s
```

is not mentioned here. The "-s" switch gives you a console with root permissions, that last until you exit it. No need to hazle around with the default settings.

Comment: Why is this down voted?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this defeats one advantage of using `sudo`: every single command is logged (so you can see what you did). You lose that logging when you open a root shell.

Comment: @guntbert surely is every command logged, but in the history of the root user.

Comment: @BeowulfOF not necessarily - the bash history is something completely different than the system log.

Comment: Every process that logs to syslog if executed via sudo does also log to syslog if executed via rootshell - your comment does not make sense. The only difference by using sudo -s is, that the shell history (bash-history) of the user won't get commands written to - but root's does.

Comment: @BeowulfOF I didn't say *syslog* - have a look at `/var/log/auth.log` after you used a sequence of single `sudo` commands and again after you executed them from a root shell, obtained by `sudo -s` or `sudo -i`.

Comment: Really, @guntbert, if you use the auth log like this, you have different problems.

Comment: @BeowulfOF now you made me curious, which ones might that be?

Comment: This will run every command under sudo credentials, something one would better avoir. This is very different from not asking password each time sudo is explicitely called.

Answer (score 4):

After seeing one too many questions from users who modified config files and were confused about why their changes were overwritten after a package upgrade, I'll note that if you want to modify `timestamp_timeout`, it is better to do it by creating a file in `/etc/sudoers.d` rather than modify `/etc/sudoers` directly.

So you should do

```
sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/timeout
```

(the name of the file can be whatever you want as long as it does not contain a period (`.`) nor end with a tilde (`~`)). Instead of opening `/etc/sudoers` in your editor of choice, it will open `/etc/sudoers.d/timeout`, normally as an empty file since it does not exist. Put your

```
Defaults timestamp_timeout=X
```

in it, and save as usual. Then if a new version of `/etc/sudoers` comes out, you don't have to choose between installing the newer version or keeping your changes--you will automatically have both.

Answer (score 1):

All of the other answers so far seem to center around changing the default timeout for how long before you have to type your password again with `sudo`. However, if you want to just be able to run commands as root without prepending every command with `sudo`, you can get a root shell with:

```
sudo -i
```

or

```
sudo bash
```

or

```
sudo <your preferred shell here>
```

While all of these do just start a single process as root, the single process in question just so happens to be a shell that will allow you to start as many other processes as you like as root without any further need to type `sudo` or a password. :)

Of course, with great power comes great responsibility, don't do stupid stuff, etc.

Comment: BE EXTREMELY CAREFUL with this. In effect you will be running a root shell.

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Comment: @hmayag Yes, if you start a root shell, you will indeed be running a root shell. Hence the reason for the warning at the end.

Comment: @coteyr Possibly for the same reason as BeoWulf's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for **a solution that doesn't change the configuration file**, for example when you want the token to last longer for a specific session, or that it applies only after an explicit action, you might try the following:

```
# Work as is with Bash 4.1.2(1)-release and later, this might require some adaptation for other shells
(while [ true ]; do sudo -v; sleep $((60*4)); done)&
```

Basically the previous code **refresh the sudo token every 4 minutes**, through a process launched in background.

Indeed, according to the `sudo` manual: *"the default password prompt timeout for the sudoers security policy is 5 minutes*." So depending on the system specific policy, you might tweak the amount of time the loop pass sleeping between two cycles.

Comment: `man sudo` for `-v` gives: Update the user's cached credentials, authenticating the user if necessary.  For the sudoers plugin, this extends the sudo timeout for another 15 minutes by default, but does not run a command. So 15 minutes it seems.

Comment: I think the password prompt timeout is if you execute sudo and get a password prompt and wait 5 minutes before actually typing in the password. Then it fails in any case